# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right|<\infty$, then $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \ q >0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+q}|<\ \epsilon$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let a absolutely summable sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right|<\infty$. Is it true that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \ q >0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+q}|<\ \epsilon$ ?

Comment: It will work for sufficiently large q

Comment: Yes, as absolute summability implies that $a_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{q\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n+q}| = \lim_{q\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n}| -\lim_{q\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{q} |a_{n}|=0.$$
Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $q>0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n+q}| <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|$ is Cauchy.

There exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $m\ge n\ge n_0$

$|s_m-s_n| <\epsilon$.

For $n=n_0$, and $m=k +n_0$ we get

$|s_{k+n_0} -s_{n_0}|= \sum_{i=1}^{k}|a_{i+n_0}| <\epsilon$.

Take the limit $k \rightarrow \infty$:

$\sum_{i}^{\infty}|a_{i+n_0}| \le \epsilon$.